# Как в java массиве заменить координаты фигур?

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Main {
    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    public static <figures> void main(String[] args) {

        Square square = new Square(5,7);
        Circle circle = new Circle(2,5);

        System.out.println("Старые координаты " + square + " : " + "  " + " x = " + square.x + "  " + " y = " + square.y);
        System.out.println("Старые координаты " + circle + " : " + "  " + " x = " + circle.x + "  " + " y = " + circle.y);


        Figure[] figures = new Figure[2];
        figures[0] = square;
        figures[1] = circle;

        for (int i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
            figures[i] = setX(8);
            figures[i] = setY(9);
        };
            System.out.println("Новые координаты " + square + " : " + "  " + " x = " + square.x + "  " + " y = " + square.y);
            System.out.println("Новые координаты " + circle + " : " + "  " + " x = " + circle.x + "  " + " y = " + circle.y);
        }

    public static Figure setX(int x) {
        Main.x = x;
        return null;
    }

    public static Figure setY(int y) {
                Main.y = y;
        return null;
    }

}





public abstract class Figure {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Figure(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x=x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y=y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Как вы рассчитываете изменить координаты у _экземпляров_ класса `Figure`, вызывая статические методы класса `Main`, которые меняют статические же поля в классе `Main`?  В ответе показан работающий код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам IDE пишет в чем проблема, что в мейне нет такого метода, так как вам нужно вызывать этот метод у объекта `Figure`. Например

```
Figure[] figures = new Figure[2];
    figures[0] = square;
    figures[1] = circle;

    for (int i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
        figures[i].setX(8);
        figures[i].setY(9);
        };
```

И унаследовать `Square` и `Circle` от `Figure`

```
abstract class Figure {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Figure(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x=x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y=y;
    }

}

class Square extends Figure {

    public Square(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
}

class Circle extends Figure {

    public Circle(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: исправил, ошибки исчезли, однако координаты остаются старыми, не изменяются.

Comment: Не знаю как у вас унаследованы классы Square и Circle, однако у меня нормально изменяются поля.
Старые координаты Square@2ef9b8bc :    x = 5   y = 7
Старые координаты Circle@5d624da6 :    x = 2   y = 5
Новые координаты Square@2ef9b8bc :    x = 8   y = 9
Новые координаты Circle@5d624da6 :    x = 8   y = 9

Comment: @Fleckinger, пока что там реализованы статические методы в классе `Main`, которые меняют статические же поля в классе `Main`.  Нельзя просто так взять и скопировать рабочий код.

Comment: @and73 а зачем вам вообще поля и статические методы в классе Main если вы работаете с объектами наследниками Figure.
Отредактировал ответ, дополнил двумя классами унаследованными от Figure

Comment: @Fleckinger, мне они и даром не нужны, это вопрос к автору.

Comment: @Fleckinger, сделал один в один , а в мэйне setX и setY подсвечивает красным (Cannot resolve method 'setX' in 'Main')
и в Figure ругается на методы setX и setY - 1 related problem

Comment: @Fleckinger Ура! Получилось!!! Спасибо вам большое!!!

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Answer (score 0):

вы меняете не те переменные .
Вы меняете статические переменные в классе Main, вам следует менять их, обращаясь к фигуре.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось и работает как надо.

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Square square = new Square(5,7);
        Circle circle = new Circle(2,5);

        System.out.println("Старые координаты " + square + " : " + "  " + " x = " + square.x + "  " + " y = " + square.y);
        System.out.println("Старые координаты " + circle + " : " + "  " + " x = " + circle.x + "  " + " y = " + circle.y);

        Figure[] figures = new Figure[2];
        figures[0] = square;
        figures[1] = circle;

        for (Figure figure : figures) {
            figures[0].setX(square.movex());
            figures[0].setY(square.movey());
            figures[1].setX(circle.movex());
            figures[1].setY(circle.movey());
        }
        System.out.println("Новые координаты " + square + " : " + "  " + " x = " + square.x + "  " + " y = " + square.y);
        System.out.println("Новые координаты " + circle + " : " + "  " + " x = " + circle.x + "  " + " y = " + circle.y);
    }
}


abstract class Figure {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Figure(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
            }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
            }
}



public interface Moveable {
    int movex();
    int movey();
}
```